# Apply CSS to Django Form Wizard

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I´m working with the Form Wizard which is alright but right now its not really pretty.

My Views.py is based on the docs:

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
form_list = [DurationForm, ContactForm2]
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    return render(self.request, 'done.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],
    })
```

My done.html contains:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1> Done! </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

My forms are defined  in forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class DurationForm(forms.Form):
     Duration_in_secounds = forms.IntegerField()

class FrequencyForm(forms.Form):
     Frequency_in_time_interval = forms.IntegerField()
```

Now i wonder how the forms even render because i never load them the way i used (for example with

```
{{form.as_p}}
```

Because whatever i change in my done.html doesnt affect the forms created with the wizard i have no idea how to add css to them.

Could any of you help me get whats going on here?
(sorry if the question is stupid/ already asked -  its quite late here and i couldn´t find anything for the last two hours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it doesn't matter it's a Form Wizard. You can just create a base class that you have `DurationForm` and `ContactForm2` extend from. For example:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BaseFormClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # specific field
    self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'my_class'

    # all fields on form
    for field in self.fields:
         self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'my_class'
```

Not tested.

Comment: Thanks! Even though i abandoned the wizard i am using something similar to your solution for my form .
Theres only one thing still missing:
Adding the class in attrs worked for every form except the checkbox form. This might be because i need to specifiy a type in the html but adding this to the attrs didnt work out for me :/

`forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-group', 'type':'checkbox',}), choices = CHOICES_AGE) 
`

Any idea what i´m  missing?
If not i will greate another question for this (googling didnt help until now :b)

Comment: Maybe try adding in the attr in the `MultipleChoiceField` instead

Comment: then i get an unexpected argument error -  i´ll comment the soution here too once i found it =)

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: the form itself? with {{ form.as_p}}
The error occurs when i try ` Target_Age = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices = CHOICES_AGE, attrs={'class':'form-check', 'input_type':'checkbox',} ) `

Comment: Try it without choices?

Comment: Ok, dunno then.

Answer (score 0):

You should add load static to your template (html):

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'myapp/css/my.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is where the css, scripts, etc. are loaded.